# How can I recursively generate lambda functions based on previously generated ones?

Tags: python, lambda

SOLVED:

The problem is the references to `ii` in the lambda, which get looked up by name at the time the function is called. By that time, `ii` has its final value, equal to n, rather than the proper value for that level of the function. One fix would be to write the function as `lambda x, ii=ii:` ... to capture `ii`'s value at the time of definition.

Thank you @jasonharper

---

I am trying to generate a lambda function based on the Hermite series, which is a series of polynomial equations that rely on previous terms to calculate them. I am sure that a closed-form definition exists, but I am required to calculate them recursively. My function should return a lambda function representing the correct polnomial given the value of n. Here is my current attempt:

```
def hermite(n):
    functions = [None]*(n+1)
    first = lambda x: x-x+1 # just setting it to 1 causes issues.
    second = lambda x: 2*x
  
    functions[0] = first
    if n == 0:
        return functions[n]
    functions[1] = second 
    if n == 1:
        return functions[n]

    for ii in range(2,n+1):
        functions[ii] = lambda x: 2*x*functions[ii-1](x) - 2*(n-1)*functions[ii-2](x)
        
    return functions[n]
```

I tested it with this code:

```
xvals = np.linspace(-3,3,1001)
f = hermite(2) #changing this number to 3 breaks my code
yvals = f(xvals)
plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
```

I believe that the for loop should recursively genereate lambda functions up to n, and it does generate the n=2 polynomial correctly. However, when I try to generate the n=3 polynomial, I can no longer use it. Why does it break for the *second* iteration of the for loop, not the first, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does "I can no longer use it" mean?  If there was an error, we need to see the full traceback message.

Comment: The problem is the references to `ii` in the lambda, which get looked up by name at the time the function is called.  By that time, `ii` has its final value, equal to `n`, rather than the proper value for that level of the function.  One fix would be to write the function as `lambda x, ii=ii: ...` to *capture* `ii`'s value at the time of definition.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I will update with the solution and then close the question.

Comment: Also, that `(n-1)` in the lambda cannot possibly be right.  `functions[2]`, for example, has a fixed definition: it shouldn't depend on the number of functions you intend to define!

Comment: I swear the (n-1) is correct. The Hermite series is bizarre. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say you're "required to use recursion", do you mean that literally? Because you aren't currently using recursion, you're using iteration.

Comment: You can add your "solved" session as an answer instead of as an edit - that way your questions and answers in S.O. can be properly boostraped. As it is, it is more likely the question will be closed, and you will forfeit some rep points that could allow you to comment and vote in other questions.